# Check if multiple pd.DataFrames are equal

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a Pythonic way (no loops or recursion) to check if *more than two* pd.DataFrames (e.g., a list of pd.DataFrames) are equal to each other?

Comment: @sammywemmy - it not check equality

Comment: u r right @jezrael, it actually doesnt

Comment: Try wrapping multiple df.equals() functions in an all() function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like:

```
all(x.equals(dfs[0]) for x in dfs)
```

with `dfs` the list of dataframes. This checks if they are all equal to the first - which I think is equivalent to asking if they are all equal to one another.

Comment: Sincerely wondering if this isn't just a one-liner to iterate over dataframes, something OP mentioned he didn't want. Either way, have an upvote since it's a sweet one-liner.

Comment: Without having that much under-the-hood knowledge... I do think you're right :p

Comment: Exactly what I was referring to in my comment on the OP. And what @JvdV said, nice onliner.  Very Pythonic.  Upvote!